# Term for a person who is fond of stationery items

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any term for a person who is fond of collecting stationery items (pens,books,etc)? If yes, then what is it?

Comment: This strikes me as likely similar to [terms of venery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal).  There is a name for practically every group of animal, but these don't have much currency in common use.  It may be interesting to speak of a convocation of eagles or a bale or turtles, but in everyday speech I'd just say, "look at all those eagles."  Likewise, there are those who will insist on being called numismatists, while others are fine with coin collector.  So while there probably is a term, just saying "stationery collector" is better nine times out of ten

Comment: You're a hallmaphile.

Comment: People who collect paper and such like can be referred to as ephemerists because they collect ephemera. But it's for paper-based stuff mostly...

Comment: ..apart from that you are a pen collector and bibliophile.

Comment: I've found **stapler enthusiast** on the invaluable [Stapler of the Week](http://stapleroftheweek.blogspot.co.uk/) site; however, the blog gives a disclaimer: 'While not pretending to be the authority on stapling, the _Stapler of the Week_ ...

Answer (score 2):

"Papyrophilia" http://papyrophilia.tumblr.com/   "This is a blog dedicated to the beauty of paper. From books to stationery to notebooks to everything paper (including pens and office supplies)."

"By now it is evident to myself and to everyone around me that I have papyrophilia, or the obsessive love of paper products, otherwise known as addiction to stationery." http://thechloebook.blogspot.gr/2014/10/on-papyrophilia.html

papyrophiliac "those who love paper"

Comment: But 'stationery items' includes far more than paper, and I suspect that people collecting office equipment or just stationery items rarely include reams of paper.

Comment: "Papyrophilia" http://papyrophilia.tumblr.com/  "This is a blog dedicated to the beauty of paper. From books to stationery to notebooks to everything paper (including pens and office supplies)."

Comment: ephemerist for a collector of such things....

Comment: The site also contains 'writersblockea'. This is hardly a reliable source for determining standard usage.

Comment: "By now it is evident to myself and to everyone around me that I have papyrophilia, or the obsessive love of paper products, otherwise known as addiction to stationery." http://thechloebook.blogspot.gr/2014/10/on-papyrophilia.html

Comment: But these are not authoritative sources. This word (or candidate word)  does not appear in ODO, CDO, M-W, Collins, AHDEL ... One definition in an academic work for 'papyrophilia' is 'preference for paper sources in the  establishing of fact'. There aren't many examples of 'papyrophiliac' on the internet; most examples of 'papyrophilia' seem to be cute proper-noun offerings. cobaltduck's response is far more balanced.

Answer (score 0):

***stationery freak***

> freak
>
> a :  an ardent enthusiast *film freaks*
>
> b :  a person who is obsessed with something *a control freak*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freak)

***stationery fiend***

> fiend
>
> :  a person extremely devoted to a pursuit or study :  fanatic *a golf fiend*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiend)

***stationery nut***

> nut
>
> :  a person who is very interested in or enthusiastic about something *a sports nut*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nut)

***stationery geek***

> geek
>
> [USUALLY WITH MODIFIER] A knowledgeable and obsessive enthusiast:
>   *a computer geek*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/geek#geek)

Comment: I feel this list is incomplete without "stationery otaku".

Answer (score -1):

A general purpose suffix meaning "lover of" is *-phile*:

> a combining form meaning “lover of,” “enthusiast for” that specified by the  initial element:
>
> *Anglophile; bibliophile; demophile.*
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-phile)]

So I would just say *stationeryphile*.

(Stan Laurel of Laurel and Hardy was a stationeryphile, by the way. He used to tour stationery stores and admire the wares.)

Comment: True, but we can't add any suffix to any word just like that. There are rules and conventions.

Answer (score -2):

I propose we lovers of all things stationery call ourselves *stationerphilliacs*. The word does not exist, but I believe it would be bliss to know we have this condition named--especially as the art of handwriting and keeping analog records is quickly being wiped out by digital technology.

Comment: Any reason for -philiac rater than -phile. I know many words with the suffix -phile, meaning "lover of", the only word I know ending -philiac is "haemophiliac", which is someone with a medical condition of the blood. (I assume whoever named the condition had a reason for using the "love" root, but I'm not sure what the reason was.)