# What is a word to describe a person that loves all things paper?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word to describe a person that ... loves all things paper; the best stationery, journals, handmade paper, expensive wrapping paper, etc.
The kind of person who travels to other countries to visit stationery stores.

Comment: You realize that stationery isn't the same thing as stationary,  right?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/317970/14666 (Closed).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you might be looking for -

## Papyrophiliac

> Are you a papyrophiliac? That is someone who’s obsessed with the love of paper products,
> otherwise known as addiction to stationery.

([Source](https://www.lomasoffice.co.uk/tell-tell-signs-youre-addicted-stationery/))

Someone who is a papyrophiliac has papyrophilia.

> “*Papyrophilia*” means an obsessive love of paper, and it seems to be
> the nearest I can get to an obsession over stationery – or writing
> equipment and office supplies in general.

([Source](https://librepaley.com/2018/12/01/papyrophilia/))

Comment: Thank you yes I am ...lol