# Is there a word to describe a love of stationery and journaling

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (preferably one that begins with C or K) that describes a love of stationery, journaling, or writing, for example.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that there is such a word?

Comment: What efforts have you made to find such a word for yourself?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. Other questions don't include the "starts with a C" part.

Comment: *calligraphilia*, maybe (according to the internets) — but it’s not a really word...

Comment: The original links that supplied answers to the OP's questions were wiped out when the post was reopened. So here they are again 1. [**What is a word to describe a person that loves all things paper?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513234/) 2. [**Term for a person who is fond of stationery items**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317970/)

Comment: @alphabet If the OP is doing a crossword puzzle and they know for a certainty the solution begins with a C or K they can edit the question and clarify. And also share their research.